Current year is commonly being typoed as an Amicable Number
Note: I created this puzzle.
There is a pair of Amicable Number (A,B), with B being typoed as the current year.
Both A and B have the same calendar, and date of Easter of year B is same as A.
As for A, the next leap year after A is divisible by a prime number (the first two digits of A - the last two digits of A) times.
What is the pair of Amicable Number A, B with B is frequently typoed as the present year?

This is the amicable pair

 $(2620, 2924)$,

since

 9 is next to 0 on the keyboard, hence 2024 could be often typoed as 2924.

Indeed,

 both years start on Saturdays and both are leap years including 29 February ("have the same calendar"), and Easter Sunday will be on 16 April both in 2620 and in 2924.

The next year after $A$ would be

 2624, which is divisible by 2 six times, and 6=26-20 from $A=2620$.

